# Nextjs restore Cache Container

Tags: reactjs, caching, next.js, node-modules

```
- ready started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000

<t> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] restore cache container: 231.681021 ms
<t> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] restore cache container: 347.670912 ms
    [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Restored pack from /home/azzam/Desktop/car_app/.next/cache/webpack/client-development.pack.gz, but version doesn't match.
<t> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] restore cache container: 390.732339 ms
    [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Restored pack from /home/azzam/Desktop/car_app/.next/cache/webpack/server-development.pack.gz, but version doesn't match.
- event compiled client and server successfully in 801 ms (20 modules)
- wait compiling...
- event compiled client and server successfully in 490 ms (20 modules)
    [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Pack got invalid because of write to: ResolverCachePlugin|normal|default|dependencyType=|esm|path=|/home/azzam/Desktop/car_app|request=|/home/azzam/Desktop/car_app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-refresh-utils/dist/runtime.js
    [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Storing pack...
    [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Capturing build dependencies... (/home/azzam/Desktop/car_app/next.config.js, /home/azzam/Desktop/car_app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/)
<t> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] resolve build dependencies: 71.17738 ms
<t> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] snapshot build dependencies: 9.646366 ms
    [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Captured build dependencies
    [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] 33 fresh items in cache put into pack 0
<t> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] store pack: 141.935581 ms
    [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Stored pack (33 items, 1 files, 1 MiB)
```

I was trying to run my nextapp I got this messsage in the terminal everyting is working but I don't know from Where I got this problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.